# Why does naming the service "service" not work in integration tests?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have a test integration test as shown below.

```
  package bibs

    import static org.junit.Assert.*
    import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase;

    import org.junit.*

    class BibsServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase{


        BibsService service

        @Before
        void setUp() {
            // Setup logic here

        }

        @After
        void tearDown() {
            // Tear down logic here


        }

        @Test
        void testSomething() {

            assertEquals service.convertRangeStringToRangeList("asd"), "asd"

        }
    }
```

When i run the integration test, the error i get is

```
 Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
| Failure:  testSomething(bibs.BibsServiceTests)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method convertRangeStringToRangeList() on null object
    at bibs.BibsServiceTests.testSomething(BibsServiceTests.groovy:30)
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 292ms
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in
```

If i change the name of the service to something other than service like

```
BibsService bibsService
```

Then the test passes. I am wondering why this is the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some confusion between Unit and Integration tests.

When writing a unit test against a service (e.g. BibsService) you can use the @grails.test.mixin.TestFor which injects the service into the test under the variable "service".

Example:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
@TestFor(BibsService)
BibsServiceSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {
  void "Test service exists"() {
    expect:
    null != service
  }
}
```

When writing an Integration test, Grails uses spring injection to make the service beans available. This means you need the name of the service bean (e.g. bibsService) when using it in an integration test. For Grails services this is typically the first character lower-cased followed by the rest of the name.

Example

```
BibsServiceSpec  extends spock.lang.Specification {
  // Injected via spring.
  BibsService bibsService

  ... Do test here ...
}
```